# Boolean value is not showing in Linux environment using Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.4.0.And create an application and deploy on linux.

My Domain is

```
class UserDetails {

  String  userEnvironment =   ""
  Long  userId          =   0L
  Boolean accountCreated  =   false
  Integer retries         =   0
  String  password        =   ""
  boolean accountCreationInProgress = true

 static constraints = {
    accountCreationInProgress nullable : true
 }

}
```

When saving its working fine on windows.But accountCreated and accountCreationInProgress column is blank on linux. Why don't know.

Anyone please help me out.

Comment: Why do you use `boolean accountCreationInProgress` as nullable instead of `Boolean`? What database are you using? Is it the same under windows and under linux deployment?

Comment: using mysql database

Comment: if i say delete UserDetails  c where c.accountCreated = true its not deleting records.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
class UserDetails {

    StringuserEnvironment = ""
    LonguserId= 0L
    Boolean accountCreated= false
    Integer retries = 0
    Stringpassword= ""
    Boolean accountCreationInProgress = true

    static constraints = {
    //there is no point to use nullable for accountCreationInProgress if you set it default to true value during create
    }

}
```

**Remember to drop table in database before rerun of app.**

Comment: Is it really work?  and the delete query would work.

Comment: yes. `UserDetails.findAllByAccountCreated(true).each{it.delete(flush:true)}`

Comment: UserDetails.executeUpdate("delete UserDetails c where c.accountCreated = 1")  what about this.?

Comment: I try **not** to use prepared statements in such a simple queries so test it yourself.

Comment: UserDetails.executeUpdate("delete UserDetails c where c.accountCreated = 1")  Its working on windows environment but not in linux environment.

Comment: Please be more specific: what error do you get? Is my solution working? If you change `where c.accountCreated = 1` to `where c.accountCreated = true` is it working?